# Are point particles the reason for 'infinities' in QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, point-particles

One of my professors told us this semester, that the 'infinities' that arise in QFT are partly due to the use of the $\delta$-distribution in the commutator relations which read (for fermions)

$\left\{\Psi(r'), \Psi^\dagger(r)\right\} = \delta(r-r')$

In reality we would not have such a $\delta$-distribution but an extended version of it.

Is this view correct? And if definitely yes, is my following view wrong?

As far as I understand it, the $\delta$-distribution is due to the fact that we deal with point particles. If e.g. the electron was an extended particle, then the $\delta$-distribution would be 'finite'.

Since [experiments](http://cerncourier.com/cws/article/cern/29724) pin down the extension of a particle to $R < 10^{-18}m$ it is also likely that the $\delta$-distribution should really be there.

Comment: The fact that $\delta (0)=\infty$ is really enough to see that this will yield some infinities when (anti-)commutation relations have to be employed. Since we don't measure $\infty$ in experiments, I think it's reasonable to say that this mathematical framework is an idealization.

Comment: I guess what my professor meant was infinities that we get when calculating cross sections. The $\delta$-distribution is of course infinit at $r = r'$, but it is well defined if we assume that we integrate over it to get the cross section. What I am more interested in is, what is the physics behind the $\delta$-distribution? Is it's occurrence really due to the concept of point particles in QFT?

Comment: I'm afraid you will get things like $\delta^2(x)$ or even higher power to integrate, in such case if you calculate cross section it is not just that at certain point you get a infinite density, it is that the total cross section also become infinite, which is unphysical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes -- they are the cause of *ultraviolet* (short distance) infinities in QFT. QFT could also have some other infinites in the *infrared* (large distance), which roughly come from massless degrees of freedom.

$10^{-18} m \sim 10 TeV$ (since $1000 nm \sim 10 eV$ ) is *not that small* for us, since we understand physics till almost one order of magnitude below that scale, and field theories seem like good working descriptions. So if the $\delta$-functions get resolved, it has to be at a *much* smaller length scale. Eg: String theory proposes one possible way of resolving them, by saying that if you zoomed in, you'd see vibrating extended objects (strings).